# Right join multiple dataframe by one column

Tags: r, dataframe, list, merge, reduce

I have these three dataframes `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.

```
df1<- structure(list(ControlRate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("24000", 
"26000", "28000", "30000"), class = "factor"), Mean = c(92.914223793805, 
125.810174859037, 152.350610715905)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(ControlRate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("24000", 
"26000", "28000", "30000"), class = "factor"), SD = c(19.7498590603068, 
33.5137097117632, 40.4792131612947)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

df3 <- structure(list(ControlRate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("24000", 
"26000", "28000", "30000"), class = "factor"), Count = c(36L, 
117L, 198L)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Instead of using `cbind(df1,df2$SD, df3$Count)`, I wanted to use merge as below but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "ControlRate", all.x = TRUE),
       list(df1, df2, df3))
```

Comment: When you say `doesn't work`, iss there any error?  I am able to run your code without any errors.  Note that when there are duplicate elements for key in all the columns, rows will be duplicated as it is not a specific join

Comment: @akrun It doesn't give me the expected result as it would with `cbind(df1,df2$SD, df3$Count)`.

Comment: Because you have dupes for the `by` column all the dataset

Comment: @akrun Is there a way to match with dups?

Comment: One way is to create a ssequence column by the 'ControlRate' in all the datasets and then do the merge with two columns

Comment: You may need `Reduce(function(...)  merge(..., by = c("ControlRate", "grp"), all.x = TRUE), lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), transform, grp = ave(seq_along(ControlRate), ControlRate, FUN = seq_along)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

list(df1,df2,df3) %>%
  map(rowid_to_column) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = c("rowid","ControlRate")) %>% 
  select(-rowid)

#>   ControlRate      Mean       SD Count
#> 1       24000  92.91422 19.74986    36
#> 2       24000 125.81017 33.51371   117
#> 3       24000 152.35061 40.47921   198
```